# Existence of infimum of partially ordered subsets

Tags: order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I've been attempting to solve the following problem for hours on end but there is one crucial part that I just can't seem to get right:

Let $( S, \geq )$ be a partially ordered subset of $( T, \geq )$. Prove that if $t=inf_T E$ , for some $E \subseteq S$, then

$$t=inf_T ( [t》\cap S )$$

Where [t》= {$x\in T$|$x \geq t$}.

Now, I've managed to show that IF $inf_T ( [t》\cap S )$ exists, then it equals t, however I am lost as to how to prove the existence of this infimum.

I'd really appreciate some hints, tips, solutions etc.

Thanks, 
Marius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if we just follow the definitions? First let me restate your question in normal notation, because your notation makes my head spin.

Suppose that $(T,\le)$ is a partially ordered set, $E\subseteq S\subseteq T,$ and $t$ is the greatest lower bound of $E$ (in the partially ordered set $T$); we want to show that $t$ is also the greatest lower bound of $\{x\in S:x\ge t\}.$

Clearly $t$ is a lower bound of $\{x\in S:x\ge t\}.$ Let $u$ be any lower bound of $\{x\in S:x\ge t\};$ we have to show that $u\le t.$ Since $u$ is a lower bound of $\{x\in S:x\ge t\},$ and since $E\subseteq\{x\in S:x\ge t\},$ it follows that $u$ is also a lower bound of $E.$ Since $u$ is a lower bound of $E,$ while $t$ is the greatest lower bound of $E,$ it follows that $u\le t.$

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Use $t=\inf_T E$ to get $[t\rangle\cap S\supseteq E$ so any lower bound must be $\leq_T t$.  Can you finish off from here?